# Iterate over array in v-for without knowing key-value pair beforehand

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[ { Articulo: "Producto 1", Precio: "2.95" }, { Articulo: "Producto 2", Precio: "2.95" }  ]
```

I want to use a `v-for` loop to iterate through the objects in order to display a div with text like this:

```
Articulo -> Producto 1

Articulo -> Producto 2
```

However, since the array is autogenerated from a function I don't know the key / value pairs beforehand, so I don't know how can I show that info in my template.

Any idea how I can approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only the want the first property, you could do this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      arr: [
        { Articulo: "Producto 1", Precio: "2.95" },
        { Articulo: "Producto 2", Precio: "2.95" }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="obj in arr">
    {{ Object.keys(obj)[0] }} -> {{ Object.values(obj)[0] }}
  </div>
</div>
```

<sup>(There used to be no guarantee of property order in JavaScript for ensuring you get `Articulo` instead of `Precio`, but pretty sure that's a non-issue nowadays and especially with Vue CLI.)</sup>

If you want all properties, you can loop over the object key/value pairs:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      arr: [
        { Articulo: "Producto 1", Precio: "2.95" },
        { Articulo: "Producto 2", Precio: "2.95" }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="obj in arr">
    <div v-for="(value, key) in obj">
      {{ key }} -> {{ value }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```